# Itemize list misaligned in Moderncv

Tags: lists, itemize, moderncv

EDIT: Updated Tex Live and problem no longer occurs. Thanks!

--

Im writing my CV with the `moderncv` class.

When I insert a list in a `cventry` the bullet points in the description don't line up with the text above. I.e. the bullet points are moved to far to the left.

Am i doing something wrong here, and how do I line up the bullet points?

Im using `XeLaTeX` in TeXmaker on Mac OS X.

Example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}     

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{street. number}{PLZ Stadt}{Land}  

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Working experience}
\cventry{year}{Boss}{Company}{City}{}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2:
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They line up good in miktex for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps your `moderncv` is outdated? I use TeX Live2015 and `moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an update of TeX Live and moderncv solved the problem.